# How do I deploy Firebase Database Security rules using the command line?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-tools

In older versions of Firebase, we could add a `rules` section to our `firebase.json` file, and upload new security rules on every deploy.

How do we use the `firebase-tools` v3 command-line tools to deploy database security rules?

[This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deployment) says that it's possible: "Rules for Firebase Storage"

[This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) hints that the command line tools can do it, but `firebase --help` and `firebase deploy --help` don't seem to hint at how to do it? (Apologies if I missed it...)

(related: where is the canonical doc for everything that can go into `firebase.json`? I found it on the old Firebase site, but can't find it via search on the new docs.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `firebase deploy --only database` if you only want to update database rules. It will overwrite your existing rules.

You can check out [Firebase CLI Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys) for more info

Comment: if using Firestore: `firebase deploy --only firestore`

Answer (score 30):

You can use `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only database` from the command line, **BUT most important:**

Please note **hereunder** `firebase.json` **format**: The `"rules"` entry is **under** `"database"` entry.

It was taken from [Firebase Sample code.](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/web/firebase.json)

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database-rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "database-rules.json",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

To deploy a new set of security rules with firebase cli

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
```

Comment: I prefer this over the `... -- only database`
Thanks @ChadlyM

Answer (score 10):

To deploy a new set of security rules, add a `rules` top-level key to your `firebase.json`.

Example `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "rules": "firebase_rules.json",
  "hosting": {
    "public": "doc",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `firebase_rules.json` is a JSON file that contains the security rules. Here's an example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

When you run `firebase deploy`, it will send the contents of `firebase_rules.json` to the server, replacing/updating any rules configurations.

Comment: This syntax didn't work for me, please see my answer here

Comment: Yes, @LiorK seems to have the correct, latest way to specify the database rules files.