# Creating "blueprints" for firebase staging and production databases?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Assume we worked on a staging real time database during development, it shaped up to be big and complex structure json. Is there any way to define blueprint for firebase's real time database so that structure from staging database can be moved to production, without data that is currently in staging database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database is a schemaless database. If you remove the actual values from the database, nothing will be left. So there also won't be anything to clone in that case.

Any rules about the data structure (validation) and access permissions are captured in [Firebase's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). If you define those in a separate file, you can use the Firebase CLI to deploy them to either environment. See this for how to do that: [How do I deploy Firebase Database Security rules using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276547/how-do-i-deploy-firebase-database-security-rules-using-the-command-line)