# Firebase rules reset by themselves

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I cannot find an answer to this in the documentation.
The default Firebase rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
   }
}
```

I have edited mine to look like this and saved them:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Without me doing anything, they randomly reset to the old rules after what seems like 12 hours. Am I missing some kind of persist option here?

Comment: No, once you've published them using the management console, they should not reset.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening? Should I be contacting support? I am just on the free Spark level.

Comment: No idea why. If you want to experiment, create another project and see if the same happens. If so, perhaps lodge it as a bug.

Comment: It seems most likely that you're deploying a firebase-rules.json as part of running `firebase deploy` with the Firebase Tools. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276547/how-do-i-deploy-firebase-database-security-rules-using-the-command-line). I thought there was also a more recent question about it, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yep, that was it. I see it in my firebase.json now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding this from the comments so others don't miss it.

> It seems most likely that you're deploying a firebase-rules.json as part of running firebase deploy with the Firebase Tools. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276547/how-do-i-deploy-firebase-database-security-rules-using-the-command-line). I thought there was also a more recent question about it, but I can't find it right now